# Is a unitary and vertical vector field projectable?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $\pi:(\tilde{M},\tilde{g})\to (\mathbb{R},g)$ be a Riemannian submersion. Given a vector field $X$ on $\tilde{M}$ which at each point $p\in\tilde{M}$ is unitary and orthogonal to $\pi^{-1}(q)$, where $\pi(p)=q.$ Now if one can guarantee that $X$ is projectable?

P.S. $X$ is projectable if for fixed $q\in \mathbb{R}$, $d\pi(X_p)$ is independent of $p\in \pi^{-1}(q)$.

Also note that each fiber is of codimension 1.

Comment: By unitary you mean "of unit length"? Unless the fibers have codimension $0$ or $1$ (i.e., $\dim \tilde M = \dim M$ or $\dim M + 1$), this seems highly unlikely.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes by unitary I mean of unit length. 
Sorry, I forgot to mention that each fiber has codimension 1. This is why I think the answer might be positive. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $$f :\pi^{-1}(q) \to T_q \mathbb R : f(p) = d\pi(X_p)$$ is continuous, and by the assumptions ($X_p \in (\ker d \pi)^\perp$, $|X_p|=1$ and the fact that $\pi$ is a Riemannian submersion) we know that $|f(p)| = 1$. Thus $f$ in fact takes values in the $0$-sphere $\{ -1, +1 \} \subset T_q \mathbb R$; so assuming the fibers are connected we conclude that $f$ is constant; i.e. $X$ is projectable.

If you allow disconnected fibers then there are obvious counterexamples - e.g. just disjoint union an example with a copy of itself where $X$ is flipped.

Comment: This $\phi$ is $\pi$?

Comment: Oops, yes. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much. So helpful :)